# Eazfuscator.Net Unable to find tool ildasm.exe

Tags: xamarin, eazfuscator

I'm trying to obfuscate my xamarin dlls with Eazfuscator.Net 3.3, but i get an error message that says 'Unable to find tool ildsam.exe'.

How can i fix this issue ?

I went for version 3.3 because i can't afford to buy their commercial version. I'm also using Visual Studio 2017 Community. Please see the screenshot below :

[image]

Answer (score 3):

find the file from somewhere under
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows

ildasm.exe
ildasm.exe.config

and copy to Eazfuscator.NET installed directory for local reference.

C:\Program Files (x86)\Eazfuscator.NET

Answer (score 0):

Eazfuscator.NET 3.3 was released in 2012. Neither Visual Studio 2017 nor Xamarin could be supported by such a dated version. You will get a much better luck with more recent Eazfuscator.NET versions.